# Laravel 4: Form::macro with Form::model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to use a custom `Form::macro()` with the `Form::model()` feature?

When I tried it at first glance, I could not get the model data to be passed to the macro method.

Comment: are you saying you tried to make a Form::macro() function that calls Form::model inside it?

Comment: No, if I use a `Form::model()` for an edit form, but inside the form is a custom made `Form::macro()`. When inside of the macro function, I cannot access the data from the model. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: If all you're doing inside the macro is outputting plain HTML, there's really no way for the field to interact with the model. The HTML is printed as is. The request for the model attributes is done inside of the Form::input function which is called any time you call a function like Form::text. So inside of your Macro, which is basically just a custom function, you need to request the model attributes yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only Form functions like Form::text will look for the form model automatically. Inside your macro, you could do this a couple of ways. Easiest would be to use `Form::getValueAttribute($name)`. For example:

```
Form::macro('myField', function() {
    $value = Form::getValueAttribute('username');
    return "<input type='text' name='username' value=$value >";
});
```

And then you'd use it in the blade template like this:

```
<?php
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = "bob";
    echo Form::model($user);
    echo Form::myField();
    echo Form::close();
?>
```

You can find all of the available form functions in the source code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was looking for. Thanks Tony.